# Creating empty back cover page

Tags: covers

In defined a document with a conditional background, this should place ornaments only in `\mainmatter` pages and exclude the title page. These are the lines with the relevant code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc}

\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\editor}[1]{%
    \def\@editor{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\theeditor}{%
    \@editor%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\eachpageornament}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, color=LimeGreen]%
        \transparent{0.75}{%
            \node[anchor=north west](CNW) at (current page.north west){\pgfornament[width=2cm]{61}};%
            \node[anchor=north east](CNE) at (current page.north east){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{61}};%
            \node[anchor=south west](CSW) at (current page.south west){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{61}};%
            \node[anchor=south east](CSE) at (current page.south east){\pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{61}};%
            \pgfornamenthline{CNW}{CNE}{north}{87}%
            \pgfornamenthline{CSW}{CSE}{south}{87}%
            \pgfornamentvline{CNW}{CSW}{west}{87}%
            \pgfornamentvline{CNE}{CSE}{east}{87}%
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\plogo}{%
    \includegraphics[width = 30mm]{logo.png}%
}

\newcommand{\psignature}{%
    \begin{flushright}
        \def\svgwidth{40mm}%
        \input{signature.pdf_tex}%
    \end{flushright}
}

\newcommand{\myback}{%
    \begin{vplace}[0.7]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width = 60mm]{logo_red.png}%
        \end{center}    
    \end{vplace}
}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.1}{sfondo}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]{%
        \transparent{0.95}\node [rectangle, rounded corners, fill=LimeGreen, anchor=south west, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=8cm] (box) at (-0.5,-10) (box){};}%
        \node[anchor=west, xshift=-2.0cm, yshift=-1cm, text width=4cm] at (box.north){\large \textit{\theeditor}};%
        \node[anchor=west, xshift=-2.0cm, yshift=-3.5cm, text width=4cm] at (box.north){\huge \thetitle};%
        \node[anchor=west, xshift=-2.0cm, yshift=-6cm, text width=4cm] at (box.north){\large \theauthor};%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
}

\makeatletter
\backgroundsetup{%
    contents={%
        \if@mainmatter%
            \eachpageornament \thepage%
        \else%
        \ifnum\value {page}=1%
        \else%
            \eachpageornament \thepage%
        \fi%
        \fi%
    },
    position=current page.north east,
    angle=0,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\poemtoc}{section}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\normalfont\large\itshape\centering} 

\pagestyle{plain}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

This's working even if the condition is somewhat redundant (in my opition).

Now I need to add a back cover page with editor logo (but also a blank page is fine) but without ornaments ... I tought to do so modifying the conditional background but as long as I can see I'm not able to do so.
I tried to modify the condition in several ways but all I got are compilation errors.
This's the document structure:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,a5paper,twoside,openright,italian,12pt]{memoir}

\input{defines}

\author{Me}
\date{2016}
\title{Title}
\editor{Editor}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mytitle

\tableofcontents

\include{Preface}

\mainmatter

\include{Chapter01}

\include{Chapter02}

\backmatter

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\myback

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this? I need a condition to exclude ornaments from the back cover page and I nedd this page to be an even page so it can be the last page on a booklet.

Comment: I noticed that option _openright_ interferes forcing the back cover page to open in the right and thus forcing latex to place extra page(s) to force it to be in a odd page that obviously lead it to be NOT in the back cover.

Answer (score 1):

the placement in the even page can be achieved with this code:

```
\clearpage \ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi
```

Comment: For an empty page, [nextpage.sty](https://ctan.org/pkg/nextpage?lang=en) works consistently.